# Mininet and NFV?

Tags: networking, sdn, mininet

Someone has tried Mininet and NFV(Network Function Virtualization)?

Specifically running hosts, switches and VNFs(Virtual Network Function) on a Mininet network.

The idea is that all the traffic from a host-source to a host-destination pass through a VNF (can be a generic network function) before reach the destination.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I tried.
With Mininet depending on what you want to run, you can have some problem with Isolation of the VNF.
For VNF I suggest you [Distrinet](https://distrinet-emu.github.io) or [Containernet](https://containernet.github.io), that are both Mininet extensions, Distrinet is using LXC to virtualize the vHost while with Containernet you can use Docker for your VNF.

I am one of the main contributors of Distrinet, so if you have questions don't hesitate to ask.
This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONfEdcwUZiA&list=PLjv6t3T3klL7B6aYsu0y3QKXPwTpVm1S7&index=7&t=1s) shows a demo of with Hadoop in vHosts and a virtual streaming server running, but you can install your VNF following the [tutorial](https://distrinet-emu.github.io/personalize_vhost.html)

Or with containernet you can check this really nice [work](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7919490) form the creators of Containernet